# Solution for invalid REQUEST_URI sent using CURL

Tags: php, apache, url

Using this php script, I can call a webservice. The file names will be recorded in a database. They are requested and non existent.

```
$url     = "http://test.com/test.php?request=file name.jpg";
$ch      = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url     );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE     );
$data = curl_exec( $ch );
print( $data );
curl_close( $ch );
```

The problem is "file name.jpg". It's not encoded.
When it gets to the webservice the request URI looks like this

```
["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(28) "/test/test.php?filename=file"
```

It truncates the url at the start of first space char.

My problem is I can't control how people are sending this request. Of course they should the urlencode function but I can't force them.

So I need a solution to get the full REQUEST URI, or catch this as an error.

Comment: As you said you can't control what kind of request you'll get. You could get anything. So I guess the only way would be to make sure that you have a correct `filename` parameter that contains a valid file name (restriction on the extension for example).

Comment: Can't do that. Some file really don't have an extension.

Comment: if people send **wrong url** - then it is their problems.

Comment: It's my webservice. I will store this information so It becomes my problem. As any invalid user input there must be a way to detect a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If people aree sending invalid requests, there is not much you can do, except detect the `$_GET['filename']` is invalid *(non-existant file, I suppose, on your server ?)*, and return them a *(`404`, probably ?)* error.

And, yes, a space should be escaped -- see section `2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters` of [**RFC 2396**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

Comment: The files don't exit. The file names are requests. I updated the question.

Comment: Oh ; too bad. If you have no way to check *(against files, or database)* whether the `filename` is correct, there is not much you can do : with the code you posted, it's exactly like if users sent `'file'`, as that's what they are actually doing -- and there is no way you can know it wasn't what they wanted to do.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the apache log shows the full url "GET /test/test.php?filename=file name.jpg HTTP/1.1" so only php can't process this ?